# Howto temporarily turn off auto formating in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, editor, autoformatting

Sometimes it would be convenient if I could temporarily turn off the auto formatting feature of Visual Studio, do some editing stuff and then turn it on again.

I don't want to go the long way into the options menu to do this.

Do you know a shortcut, addin or anything to do this?

Or maybe I can surround a section of my code with something like "#pragma dontformat" to tell the editor not to format this code?

Comment: You mean `Intellisense` with auto formatting ?

Comment: I don't know whether this is Intellisense. I mean the three flags for automatic formatting under Tools/Options/Text Editor/C#/Formatting/General.

Comment: what exactly you don't want to format, you can change the VS default settings, check also Edit->advance

Comment: VS has three checkboxes saying "Automatically format completed statement on;", "Automatically format completed block on }" and "Automatically format on paste". I want to enable/disable these checkboxes in a very fast way.

Comment: As soon as it's on again, if someone does a "format document", you'll lose whatever (custom) formatting you performed with it switched off.

Comment: That's no problem at all. As I said, I want it just temporarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for pasting is CTRL[Z].

When you paste a block of code, it gets pasted and then auto formatted. Hitting CTRL[Z] the 1st time will undo the auto formatting but leave the original pasted text. Hitting CTRL[Z] the 2nd time will then undo the pasted text as you'd expect.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 - haven't tried this in earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think about this one. Works also in VS2012.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there are no [Pre-Defined shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) for this purpose so you have to do it manually.